# Is there a name for the general type of operation that sweeps a kernel over a function (e.g. like convolution, morph. dilation, registration, etc)

Tags: integral-transforms, definitions, convolution

There is a certain family of 'sweeping' operators / functions $S(y; f,k,g)$, where:

- $f$ is a function $f : x \mapsto \mathbb{R}^N$
- $k$ is a 'kernel' function $k : x \mapsto \mathbb{R}^N$
- $y$ represents an 'offset' (independent) variable
- $g$ is a higher-order function $g : f, k; \tilde f, \tilde k, y \mapsto \mathbb{R}^N$, where

  - $\tilde f[f]$ is a higher order function modifying $f(x)$, and
  - $\tilde k[k,y]$ is a higher order function modifying $k(x)$, in a manner that depends on 'offset' $y$ $-$ i.e., $\tilde k$ results in a 'shifted' (or more generally, an 'adjusted') version of $k$ by $y$ (plus any other modifications, e.g. reflection).

In other words the kernel $k$ 'sweeps' over $f$, and for each position $y$ in the sweep, a particular function $g$ is applied, the result of which becomes the output of $S$ at that position $y$.

The most prominent example of such an operator is of course *convolution*, where function $g$ takes the specific form of an *integral transform*:

- $\tilde f[f(x)] = f(x)$
- $\tilde k[k(x), y] = k(y-x)$ $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ i.e. $k$ is reflected and offset by $y$
- $ \displaystyle g(f,k; \tilde f, \tilde k, y) = \int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^N} ~\tilde f[f(x)] ~~ \tilde k[k(x),y] ~~\mathrm{d}x $

By contrast, an example which follows the same form, but where the kernel 'adjustment' does ***not*** represent an 'offset' in the 'space sweeping' sense but is a 'multiplier' instead, is the *Fourier transform*, where: $\tilde f[f(x)] = f(x)$, $k(x) = e^{-2\pi ix}$, $~~\tilde k[k(x), y] = k(xy)$, and $g$ is the same integral transform $ \displaystyle g(f,k; \tilde f, \tilde k, y) = \int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^N} ~\tilde f[f(x)] ~~ \tilde k[k(x),y] ~~\mathrm{d}x $

Examples of other 'sweeping' functions are morphological dilation and erosion, where $g$ takes a different form involving set operations (i.e. it's not an integral transform). Yet another is in image registration, where $g$ is of the form of a similarity function plus a regularizer, etc.

**Is there a general name for this kind of 'sweeping' operation / function $S(y; ~f, k, g)$ that 'sweeps' a kernel $k$ over a function $f$, and for each position $y$ in the sweep it applies a function $g$?**

Closest I could come up with was "*kernel-based transform*" in general, though this does not seem to be a particularly accepted or used term, nor does it capture exactly what I'm referring to (in particular the 'space sweeping' aspect of such a transform). Conversely, I thought maybe it could be referred to as a "*generalised morphological operation*" but again this does not seem like an accepted or used term, nor does it capture applications in non-morphological contexts (e.g. feature detection). Any ideas?

Comment: PS. I had asked this already at [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176127/is-there-a-name-for-the-general-type-of-operation-that-sweeps-a-kernel-over-a-fu) a few days back, but it seems to be the wrong audience for it. I followed advice suggesting I can cross-post here after a few days if the original question does not generate interest there. I hope this is both ok and appropriate. Happy to delete on either site if asked to.